# Segment fault (core dumbed) x86 Assembly AT&T syntax

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu

I'm trying to write a code that takes 3 arrays and return the maximum number in the last one (Yes something like in the ProgramminGroundUp book) but I want the function to exit according to array size not when it reaches element zero
but the code gaves me

```
Segment fault (Core Dumped)
```

I use 'as' assembler' and gnu loader 'ld' 
Here is the full code

```
.section .data
first_data_items:
.long 48,65,49,25,36
second_data_items:
.long 123,15,48,67,25,69
third_data_items:
.long 102,120,156,32,14,78,100
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
pushl $first_data_items
pushl $5
call max  
addl $8, %esp
pushl $second_data_items
pushl $6
call max
addl $8, %esp 
pushl $third_data_items
pushl $7
call max
addl $8, %esp
movl %eax, %ebx
movl $1, %eax
int $0x80

.type max, @function
max:
pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
movl 8(%ebp), %ecx   #ecx will be the size of the array
movl 12(%ebp), %ebx  #ebx will be the base pointer
movl $0, %edi         #edi will be the index
movl 0(%ebx, %edi, 4), %eax   #eax will hold the maximum number
start_loop:
cmpl $0, %ecx
je end_loop
incl %edi
movl 0(%ebx, %edi,4), %esi     #esi will hold the current element
cmpl %eax, %esi
jle start_loop
movl %esi, %eax
decl %ecx
jmp start_loop 
end_loop:
movl %ebp, %esp
popl %ebp
ret
```

Comment: What does it say when you step in with a debugger like _GDB_? It seems to me there are 2 obvious problems. You loop one extra time than you should so after `movl 8(%ebp), %ecx`  I think you need to decrement _ECX_ by 1. More importantly after you get the current value in the array with `movl 0(%ebx, %edi,4), %esi` you compare it to the current high value in _EAX_. If the new value is less then you incorrectly go back to start_loop with `jle start_loop`. Doing that doesn't do `decl %ecx` You need to jump past the `movl %esi, %eax` to the `decl %ecx` if current value is less than current max

Comment: Or rewrite reading the array elements with `lodsd` and terminate loop when `esi >= array.end()` address, which will probably cut down number of instructions significantly.

Comment: I have solved it the problem was as Michael Petch said that I need to decrement ecx, so I have moved the decl instruction right after the compare between 0 and ecx and it works fine, Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have moved `decl %ecx` (Thanks to  Michael Petch) right after the compare statemnt to make ecx decrement by 1 in every loop 
so the code will be

```
.section .data
first_data_items:
.long 48,65,49,25,36
second_data_items:
.long 123,15,48,67,25,69
third_data_items:
.long 102,120,156,32,14,170,100
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
pushl $first_data_items
pushl $5
call max
addl $8, %esp
pushl $second_data_items
pushl $6
call max
addl $8, %esp
pushl $third_data_items
pushl $7
call max
addl $8, %esp
movl %eax, %ebx
movl $1, %eax
int $0x80
.type max, @function
max:
pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
movl 8(%ebp), %ecx   #ecx will be the size of the array
movl 12(%ebp), %ebx  #ebx will be the base pointer
movl $0, %edi         #edi will be the index
movl 0(%ebx, %edi, 4), %eax   #eax will hold the maximum number
start_loop:
cmpl $0, %ecx
je end_loop
decl %ecx
incl %edi
movl 0(%ebx, %edi,4), %esi         #esi will hold the current element
cmpl %eax, %esi
jle start_loop
movl %esi, %eax
jmp start_loop
end_loop:
movl %ebp, %esp
popl %ebp
ret
```

Answer (score 0):

About my comment about `lodsd` usage, example of `max` function:

```
.type max, @function
max:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    movl    8(%ebp), %ecx       # ecx will be the size of the array
    movl    12(%ebp), %esi      # esi will be the base pointer
    popl    %ebp                # stack_frame usage complete, restore ebp
    lea     (%esi,%ecx,4), %ecx # ecx = (base pointer + 4*size) (end() ptr)
    mov     $0x80000000,%edi    # current max = INT_MIN
start_loop:
    cmp     %ecx, %esi
    jae     end_loop            # end() ptr reached (esi >= ecx)
    lodsl                       # eax = [esi+=4]
    cmp     %edi, %eax          # check if it is new max
    cmovg   %eax, %edi          # update max as needed (eax > edi)
    jmp     start_loop          # go through whole array
end_loop:
    mov     %edi, %eax          # eax = current_max
    ret
```

(`CMOVcc` requires i686+ target architecture)

Comment: Actually I have googled it but it seems like I didn't reach it in the book I use
(Programming Ground up)
But it looks a good idea, Thx for ur effort it realy helped me to stretch my thoughts

Comment: @Nasser: You mean the `lods` itself? Well, in this case it can be written as `mov (%esi),%eax` `add $4,%esi` -> the code should still remain "simple" to follow for you (I hope)... If you mean the `CMOVcc`, then yes, this one is "new" for me too (I know it only about 10 years), as it was not available back when I was programming in x86 Assembly (80586 was newest), so I still feel a bit weird whenever I use it. The "string" family of functions `lods/stos/movs/scans/cmps` are part of x86 since the first 8086.

Comment: Great, it looks like a new instruction the I book I use to study doesn't include it,it was really helpful